# .match() matches only some of an identical array of strings

Tags: javascript, string-matching

I'm matching an array of strings against a regex:

```
for (let subject_index in subjects) {
      if (subjects[subject_index].match(/.*Overview of Investor.*/i)) {
        subjects.splice(subject_index, 1)
      }
    }
```

The array `subjects` contains nine identical strings, all of them `Overview of Investor`.  When I run this loop, it correctly matches five of the strings and does not match on the other four, even though all the strings are identical.  Am I missing something?

Comment: You are mutating `subjects` in your loop. That's why you are getting unexpected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're editing the array while iterating over it, which can cause weird problems. You can do this in a better way with Array.filter.

```
subjects = subjects.filter(subject => !subject.match(/.*Overview of Investor.*/i));
```

This way, you are not editing the array while reading the elements.

Edit: As noted in the comments, this solution *removes* the matched strings, because that is what the original poster's solution is trying to do. If you want to keep the matched strings, use

```
subjects = subjects.filter(subject => subject.match(/.*Overview of Investor.*/i));
```

This is the same code but without the exclamation point.

Comment: Wouldn't this return an empty array in this case? I thought he wanted to keep the matches, not discard them.

Comment: @ddastrodd They are calling `Array.splice`, which is used to remove elements from an array. Of course, you could easily change this to keep the matches, just by removing the exclamation point.

Comment: Yes, good point. I guess the wording of the question was confusing and I assumed this was an error on their part.

Answer (score 1):

Do not mutate your array within your loop. Create a new array to add your matches to.

```
let subjects = ["Overview of Investor", "Overview of Investor", "Overview of Investor", "Overview of Investor", "Overview of Investor", "Overview of Investor", "Overview of Investor", "Overview of Investor", "Overview of Investor", "Overview of Investor", "Overview of Investor"];
let ans = [];

for (let subject_index in subjects) {
      if (subjects[subject_index].match(/.*Overview of Investor.*/i)) {
        ans.push(subjects[subject_index]);
      }
 }
```